# how to display a struct inside mapping inside struct in solidity on react js frontend

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping, struct, react

I have a mapping of struct (mapping (address => struct)) inside another struct. I'm having issue in how to display the struct in the front end while using Reactjs.

[image]

Comment: `I'm having issue in how to display the struct in the front end while using Reactjs.` - is that a question??? If yes, what issues are you having? Where is the code which gives you these issues?

Comment: I am able to print all variables inside my drugData struct except drugEnvironment mapping. I have an array drugItems that contains drugData and using that array I am printing it on the frontend. DrugItems : {drugData, drugData, ...}